# 500 Internal Server Error PHPMailer

Tags: javascript, php, post, sendmail, phpmailer

Я использую `PHPMailer` для отправки данных с формы на почту. Но возникает 500 ошибка.
[image: Ошибка в консоли]

в чем проблема, не понимаю

вот `form-send.js`

```
"use strict"

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    const form = document.getElementById('form');
    form.addEventListener('submit', formSend);
})

async function formSend(e) {
    e.preventDefault();


    let formData = new FormData(form);
    let response = await fetch('sendmail.php', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formData
    });
    if (response.ok) {
        let result = await response.json();
        alert(result.message);
        formPreview.innerHTML = '';
        form.reset();
    }
    else {
        alert('Ошибка отправки заявки. Свяжитесь с нами другим способом или перезагрузите страницу.')
    }
}
```

И файл `sendmail.php`

```
<?php

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;

require 'phpmailer/src/Exception.php';
require 'phpmailer/src/PHPMailer.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
$mail->setLanguage ('ru', 'phpmailer/language/');
$mail->IsHTML(true);

$mail->setFrom('test.test@gmail.com', 'Тест');
$mail->addAddress('test.test1@gmail.com');
$mail->Subject = ('Заявка с сайта');

if(trim(!empty($_POST['name']))){
    $body.='<p><strong>Имя:</strong> '.$_POST['name'].'</p>'
}

if(trim(!empty($_POST['phone']))){
    $body.='<p><strong>Телефон:</strong> '.$_POST['phone'].'</p>'
}

if(trim(!empty($_POST['text']))){
    $body.='<p><strong>Текст:</strong> '.$_POST['text'].'</p>'
}

$mail->Body = $body;

if(!$mail->send()) {
    $message = 'Ошибка отправки заявки.';
} else {
    $message = 'Ваша заявка успешно отправлена!';
}

$response = ['message' => $message];

header('Content-type: application/json');
echo json_encode($response);

?>
```

Comment: Ошибка где-то в "sendmail.php". Нужно посмотреть во вкладке "Network", что за ошибка.

Comment: Очевидно, что сначала надо подключить файлы а потом только использовать `use`.

Comment: На будущее, тем, кто наткнется на этот вопрос. Для отображения ошибки и вообще "чего там происходит", можно указать $mail->SMTPDebug = 3 и посмотреть то, как мэйлер пытается отправить письмо.